# Understanding Memory Layouts of an Interpreter (JVM/JS)

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, interpreter, memory-layout

I am trying to understand the memory layout of a process at OS level and we are used to this diagram. [image]

Forget the multithreading part of the diagram but now for general purposes, we assume the "code" block shown in the diagram above to be the binary instructions of our program. This assumes that the code has already been compiled to now be available in its binary form. But what about interpreted languages e.g. a bytecode to be executed by the JVM interpreter. While I am choosing the JVM interpreter here, my question is for any interpreted language and how does it fit in the diagram shown above. My understanding is that the Interpreter itself is a program and therefore has to sit in the code block shown in the diagram above and the .class program in case of Java or a .js file in case of Javascript interpreters is the "argument" so to speak that this interpreter works upon to translate them to OS/machine understandable code which is then executed. Request your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of perspective whether you would consider bytecode „code“. The terminology is a bit fuzzy.

The „code“ in the diagram is native executable code, i.e. your interpreter. As far as the CPU and operating system are concerned, that is the only code that ever runs. To the OS, the bytecode being interpreted is simply data that the actual native code operates on.

That in this case, the data happens to be a form of instructions as well is a detail the CPU is unaware of and doesn‘t care about.

Comment: That is precisely what my understanding was..So during interpretation, the CPU is unaware of the fact that the native code (the interpreter code) is working on data and this data is another set of instructions that is the program that is being interpreted. Thank you so much.